# JSON.parse() function not showing the exact value needed in jQuery ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am sending success response through JSON.parse(), but I am not getting the exact value needed. I want to get values differently from the response. Below is the Jquery code i Laravel View I am using:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/user/checkout',
    cache: false,
    data: { pickupName:pickupName,locationId:locationId },
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response =='true'){
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(obj.pickup_name);

        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
    }
});
```

Below is the response I am receiving from controller in Laravel:-

`{"pickup_name":"abcd","pickup_address":"Chicago, North State Street, Chicago, IL, USA","pickup_contact":123456798}`

Now, when I try to get `pickup_name` using `obj.pickup_name` as done in above code, I don't receive pickup_name value. I am still getting the whole response. I want to get values differently in different variable, for example:-

```
var name=obj.pickup_name;
var contact=obj.pickup_contact;
```

I want to get result in different variables.

Comment: Looking at your ```response``` you don't need to do ```JSON.parse``` you can directly access by ```response.pickup_name```

Comment: @AbhinabRajopadhyaya with ```response.pickup_name``` it is giving the same whole response not a single value.

Comment: Can you post result of ```console.log(response)``` ?

Comment: `if (response == 'true')` then response is the string `true` and not a JSON object isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parse your response. You can use response.pickup_name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

From your controller:

```
{"pickup_name":"abcd","pickup_address":"Chicago, North State Street, Chicago, IL, USA","pickup_contact":123456798, "success": true}
```

Notice `success` property.

In your client:

```
if (response.success =='true'){
     alert(response.pickup_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the dataType from `'application /json'` to `json` It will work
No need to explicitly parse to json when use dataType as json

```js
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/user/checkout',
   cache: false,
   data: { pickupName:pickupName,locationId:locationId },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (response) {
       if (response =='true'){
           alert(response.pickup_name);

       }
   },
   error: function (response) {
   }
});
```